# How to echo a different title to the page if it's opened on an android mobile phone

Tags: title

How do I echo a different title to the page if it's opened on an android mobile phone?

I have this function that checks if it's an android:

```
function is_android (){
    $browserInfo = php_browser_info();
    if (preg_match("/Android/", $browserInfo['browser_name_pattern'], $matches)) {
        if ($version == '') :
            return true;
        elseif ($browserInfo['majorver'] == $version ) :
            return true;
        else :
            return false;
        endif;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I can use the statement:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'change_title_if_android');
    function change_title_if_android() {
        if ( is_front_page() &&  is_android() ){
            echo "<title> test android </title>";
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work. 
It prevents my page from loading.

I tried writing the `if` statement on the template too (header.php in the  tag) and I got the same result.

Any suggestions   ?

**Edit:**

I use the TwentyFifteen child theme I made.

I tried pasting this code part to function.php suggested by the commenter @birgire:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title )
{
    return
        is_front_page()
        && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) 
        && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' )
        ? 'Test Android'
        : $title;
}, 11 );
```

He tested it on his 2012 & 2015 default themes and it worked for him!

It didn't work for me though, so I tried using `is_home` instead of `is_front_page()`, nothing changed.

I tried to remove this line and left only the the `HTTPS_USER_AGENT`, didn't work too.

We tested `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` using this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_show_ua', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) )
    {
        printf( 'My User Agent: %s', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

and it worked. I got the right output when running `example.tld/?wpse_show_ua=1` :

> My User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G900F
>   Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/43.0.2357.93 Mobile Safari/537.36

We tested the functioanlity of the `if` statements and got it right:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_show_ua', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) )
    {
        if ( 
               isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) 
            && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' ) 
        )
            echo 'is an Android!';
        else
            echo 'not an Android!';
        exit;
    }
} );
```

On a mobile 'is an Android' and on the desktop 'not an Android!'.

So the problem is actually with sending the new value of the title!

When running this function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title )
{
    if( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_show_ua', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) )
    {
        return 'Testing 123';
    }
    return $title;
}, 11 );
```

and entering `example.tld/?wpse_show_ua=1` againg, I get my regular website display with no changes in the title!

And again - this worked on the commenter default TwentyTwelve and TwentyFifteen themes.

My guess is that it's because of the plugin that is installed (Yoast SEO). 
but I really dont know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where this `php_browser_info()` function comes from.

You can try the following instead:

```
/**
 * Modify the front/home page title for Android devices
 */
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title )
{
    return
        ( is_front_page() || is_home() )
        && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) 
        && false !== stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'android' )
        ? 'Test Android'
        : $title;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

to modiy the title of the front page.  Here we use a modification of the *Android* check from the `wp_is_mobile()` function, so please note that this detection might not be that accurate!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25065/discussion-between-birgire-and-electricwizard).

Comment: Nailed it! Works great